# Exporting Report as PDF

Tags: reporting, pdf, report-builder

This question might be duplicate, I checked stackexchange regarding this but didnt see clear answer, so posting this. How do we export a Salesforce report as pdf?
As you know, currently we can either export a report as excel or .csv but not pdf.

Is this possible through customization, if so how? I tried a Vf page to renderas pdf but dont know how to save the rendered vf page as pdf in Salesforce.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

create vf and controller with your filter logic and use following code to save vf as pdf in documents.

```
pagereference Pg = Page.Accountpdf;
Blob pdf1 = pg.getcontentAsPdf();
Document d = new Document();
d.FolderId = UserInfo.getUserId();
d.Body = Pdf1;
d.Name = 'pdf_file.pdf';
d.ContentType = 'application/pdf';
d.Type = 'pdf';
insert d;
system.debug('*****'+d.id);
```

Hope this will help you for your requirement.

Comment: This answer doesnt answer question asked by author -- "How do we export a Salesforce report as pdf?". That is just an example of how get content works

Comment: it has to be customized vf page. here accountpdf vf contains the pageblocktable to display account records.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked and still marked as the best answer, why?

Answer (score 2):

FYI .. I don't work for Cloud4J

Cloud4J’s Report Builder(http://www.cloud4j.com/report-builder.html)  is a great app that lets you schedule reports as PDF and Excel attachments (as well as many other cool features).It’s currently free, there no installation necessary, and it works with your existing Salesforce reports.To try it, simply log in with your Salesforce username and password at:https://reportbuilder.cloud4j.com/login They even have an on-premise option where you can host the app on your own servers in case you have security requirements that prevent third party apps from accessing your Salesforce data.

You can set up the Cloud4J’s Report Builder as a Web Tab in Salesforce and then add this tab to your custom Navigation menu and use it for export reports.

Below are the instructions on how to set up the Report Builder Web Tab

Go to Setup > Create > Tabs > Select New

[image]

Step 1. Choose Tab Layout

For a better experience, Full page width is the preferred layout.

[image]

Step 2. Define Content and Display Properties

Enter a Tab Label, Tab Name, and a Tab Style. Content Frame Height can be changed based on user preference, but a safe pixel height is 1000.

[image]

Step 3. Enter the URL Details

Paste the following link in the URL input box

> https://reportbuilder.cloud4j.com/webtab/login?apiSessionId={!API.Session_ID}&apiPartnerServerUrl={!API.Partner_Server_URL_340}&userId={!User.Id}&organizationId={!Organization.Id}&environmentType=Production

[image]

Step 4. Add to Profiles

[image]

Step 5. Add to Custom Apps

[image]

Comment: Note - Cloud4J requires Enterprise or higher edition.